# Multiple RDP connections to the same user

Tags: windows, rdp

Good afternoon everyone!

I have a *Windows Server 2012 R2* and I would like to allow multiple RDP connections to the *same user and session*.

For example, if *buddy1* connects to Admin user and *Buddy2* connects to Admin user as well I would like them to share the same session/desktop view.

Thanks.

Comment: You can do RDP shadowing in 2012 R2 http://microsoftplatform.blogspot.hr/2013/07/detailed-walkthrough-on-remote-control.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Alen, It's not quite what I am looking for. I'm looking forward to hear more from you guys!

Comment: There's no concept of session "sharing" with RDP. You can have one user shadow another user but you can't "share" a session between two users.

Comment: This link was helpful for me in setting up shadowing using the Server Manager GUI: http://woshub.com/rds-shadow-how-to-connect-to-a-user-session-in-windows-server-2012-r2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with RDP and is a deliberate limitation imposed by Microsoft.

Terminal Services and MultiPoint Services require an additional license and to use it the way you propose would be getting around that license restriction. I'm not saying you're doing anything nefarious; this is just the way Microsoft sees it.

In order to do this, you will need a screen sharing application that can do meetings, such as TeamViewer, GoToMeeting, LogMeIn, etc. I know from experience that TeamViewer in particular works just fine from an RDP session and supports multiple people viewing the same session at the same time.

Otherwise, your only other option is session shadowing, but buddy1 and buddy2 must still have their own accounts so they can log in to shadow Admin's session, and they also must be local amins on the server itself.

Comment: Alright then, I might need to use a 3rd party application if that's the case but for now I'll let others speak up and see if we can figure something out!

Comment: @Kjell Wes Sayeed has pretty much nailed it.  Apart from the already-suggested session shadowing, only 3rd party solutions can do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shadowing this allows to show the session of your buddy?
Some thing like remote assistance. The users needs to allow sharing the session.

Comment: The issue is that we're more than two persons who would like to access the same session hence why shadowing wouldn't be ideal in this situation, thanks for the suggestion.